# Elastic Query multi_match conditional query when no results

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have following query which is used for almost all search terms.

#### Query

```
GET test_partial/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [],
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "fields": [
                  "title^30",
                  "description^10"
                ],
                "operator": "and",
                "query": "pamers diap",
                "type": "most_fields"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Document

```
[
  {
    "title": "Huggies diapers"
  },
  {
    "title": "Huggies wipes"
  },
  {
    "title": "papmpers wipes"
  },
  {
    "title": "natureval diapers"
  }
]
```

If you check query `"operator": "and"` it works perfectly fine in terms of relevancy for all other search terms.

I have no `pampers diapers` document (I get no results)
But I have few documents with `Huggies diapers` and `pampers wipes`

If I change `"operator": "or"` I get both documents in results.

To keep relevancy top, I need to keep operator=and and switch to "OR" when no results. To achieve this I need to make 2 ES calls, is there a way we can specify conditional query when no results switch to "OR" to avoid 2 calls to ES?

Comment: I would try to create a should and the clauses inside it would be a match with operator and for the title and the other for the description, but I would also add a high boost to the matches because they would have greater weight than the multi-match. The multi-match I use operator Or to allow the retrieval of documents.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing my comment, I would try something like the query below. I have accuracy with match and recovery with multi-match.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [],
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "title": {
                  "query": "natureval diapers",
                  "operator": "and",
                  "boost": 50
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "description": {
                  "query": "natureval diapers",
                  "operator": "and",
                  "boost": 30
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "fields": [
                  "title^30",
                  "description^10"
                ],
                "operator": "or",
                "query": "natureval diapers",
                "type": "most_fields"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's one way of doing, thanks for trying. But I always get 10,000 as total hits, which wouldn't ideal to show to customers.